# how to coat truffles with chocolate

Tags: chocolate, melting

I need help please, I have just made my first batch of truffles. I decided to coat them in chocolate (untempered) but after I had dipped about 8 the chocolate started to go too hard. I tried to melt it again but it just got more solid. What did I do wrong? I have lots of truffle mix left so need to coat at least 30 more! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you get some water into your chocolate or how did you melt it? What are you using to coat your truffles?

Comment: I wonder if the truffle mixture contained a bit a bit of water from cream/butter/whatever.  Could that be enough to make the chocolate seize?

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. I think it must have been water in the chocolate. So much to learn :o)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you coat perfectly round truffles with melted chocolate?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/45977/how-do-you-coat-perfectly-round-truffles-with-melted-chocolate)

Comment: @Catija I don't think this is a dup; the OP had trouble keeping the chocolate at the right consistency to dip, not trouble with dipping/coating the truffles evenly.

Answer (score 3):

Working with chocolate is so tricky!

Introducing even a tiny amount of water to melted chocolate will cause it to seize. The water could come from unexpected places: steam from a double boiler, condensation on the interior of a lid, the use of a wet utensil. Seized chocolate can be returned to a smooth, melty texture, but it will no longer be suitable for coating. It can be put to other uses, though.

However, you may have overheated your chocolate, which will also cause it to seize - overheated chocolate can be saved, though. Blending overheated chocolate with solid chocolate, or pressing it through a sieve, may save it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes very tricky, I managed to coat the remaining truffles yesterday, and they came out well. My next challenge is to attempt to temper the chocolate so it does not melt on your fingers the moment you pick the truffle up. All suggestions gratefully received.